# How to convert Bytes (UTF-8) embeded emoji in a string

Tags: python, utf-8, emoji

I am scraping a data from WhatsApp chat backup (chat.txt). It looks like this :

```
7/21/20, 1:31 PM - mark: Can we look google  
7/21/20, 1:31 PM - elon: No  
7/21/20, 1:31 PM - mark: Can we smile ?  
7/21/20, 1:31 PM - elon: Ya
```

While I used line by line extraction

```
with open ('chat.txt','rb') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(str(line.strip()))
```

I got this:

```
b'7/21/20, 7:37 AM - mark: Can we look google\xf0\x9f\xa4\xa9\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82'
b'7/21/20, 7:37 AM - elon: No'
b'7/21/20, 1:31 PM - mark: Can we smile ?'
b'7/21/20, 7:37 AM - elon: Ya\xf0\x9f\x98\x82'
```

1. How can we git rid of `b''` ? ( I tried `.decode('utf-8')`, but it didn't work)
2. How can I convert

   ```
   Can we look google\xf0\x9f\xa4\xa9\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82
   ```

   to

   ```
   Can we look google?
   ```

Comment: iam using python, and each lines like "7/21/20, 1:31 PM - mark: Can we look google" is a new line in chat.txt .. i coudn't incoperate a new line in the question   ... similarly each b' ' in the output is also a new line

Comment: Can you explain your first question? I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file with the right encoding, not binary mode:

```
with open ('chat.txt', encoding='utf8') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line, end='')
```

How well this works depends on your execution environment. You need a terminal/IDE and font that support *printing* the code points for `print` to be successful, but that is not a Python issue.

Comment: The encoding may not even need to be specific explicitly. Opening a file in text mode causes each read to automatically decode the input according to the current locale's default encoding if no encoding is specified.

Comment: @chepner explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: You can overdo explicit.